# Oracle trigger - update column on newly inserted record

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g, insert-update

In My Oracle (Express) DB I have a table with a column, named `created`(date type).
What I am trying to do, is to create a trigger that will update that column after an update or insert, was done, with `SYSDATE`.

My sql (for insert only, I know, it fails anyway) is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "VIRTUAL_COUNTERS_NEW" 
AFTER
insert on "VIRTUAL_COUNTERS"
begin
new.updated := SYSDATE
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "VIRTUAL_COUNTERS_NEW" ENABLE
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix new with a colon character and add *for each row* so that the update is for each row in case of multiple rows insert:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  VIRTUAL_COUNTERS_NEW
BEFORE
insert on VIRTUAL_COUNTERS
FOR EACH ROW
begin
  :new.updated := SYSDATE;
end;
/
```

Comment: To change values on-the-fly, the trigger must be `BEFORE` and yossi wants to include `UPDATE` statements, so it must be `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON VIRTUAL_COUNTERS FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: @acesargl Right you are